# Changing highlighted button color in VS2010

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

I'm working on a GUI built with C# in Visual Studio 2010. I want to change the color of some of my buttons, which I can do in the properties of the button, but a small border remains around the edge of the colored part of the button. When the button is clicked or focused on, this border changes to the default blue. Like this:

[image]

How can I change the highlight color of the button? Also, is there a way to change the color of the button while maintaining the default (horizontally divided two-tone) look?

Thanks for your help,

Dave

Comment: @Sylca I've tried changing pretty much all of the color properties, backColor, foreColor, etc., but nothing really seems to be applicable.

Comment: I've been searching something about this topic of yours and found something but it's linked to WPF and I you're working with winforms. Anyway, take a look at it! First link:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613567.aspx and second one:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744790.aspx

Comment: I think there is no simple ways. You have to overwrite the Paint event.

Comment: There is no simple way. I was trying to do the same thing on a proyect I´m working on. I solved it by using a WPF user control element. Just add it to your proyect, then drag a button and change the colors using XAML. You can use gradients there so you can have 2 or more colors in your button. After that, insert the WPF user control in your winform. It´s really easy. I dont know if you are familiar with WPF, but there are a lot of examples in the web, so you just need to  copy code to do what you want. Hope that helps! And if you need the code to make that work just tell me.